# Checking if a process has a window

Tags: go, window, exec, topmost

In my Go code, I'm starting an external GUI application (Firefox), and I'm trying to make it the front window (the top most window). After trying `robotgo`, I found out that it didn't work because when I called `ActivePID`, the window still hasn't loaded, so there wasn't a window for robotgo to set to top-most.

How can I detect when Firefox has loaded it's GUI? (in a cross-platform way)

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("firefox")
cmd.Start()
robotgo.ActivePID(int32(cmd.Process.Pid))
cmd.Wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone also comes across this problem, I found out that `robotgo` has an API called `robotgo.GetPID`, which gets the process id of the current active window!

That means that we can repeatedly check if `robotgo.GetPID` returns our target process id or not:

```
for int32(processID) != robotgo.GetPID() {
    robotgo.ActivePID(int32(processID))
}
```